# 90's anime, set in a forest where people transform

Tags: anime, story-identification

In the show the people turned into some kind of monster, like robots. It was from the 90's and most of the show was in a forest. I watched it once and don't remember the name of it.

The big problem is that I don't recall if it was a TV show or a movie, and I have being looking for it for 5 to 7 years. I have been unable to find it at any store or online. Has anyone heard of it?

Comment: Can you add more information please?

Comment: Some punctuation wouldn't go amiss either :)

Comment: Anime where people transform in a forest… That's really not enough information. What else do you remember? Did they all transform into the same monster? Did everybody transform or just a few? Was the transformation voluntary or not? Did they transform back?

Comment: Very vague.  What is 'like robots'?  When did you see it and where?  Online?  Cable TV?

Answer (score 3):

I think this could possibly be [The Guyver](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488266/), which had a number of incarnations:

- The first [Movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guyver:_Out_of_Control)
- The Original [OVA series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guyver_%28OVA%29)
- The [Live action film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101988/)
- The [Sequel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109965/?ref_=tt_rec_tti) to said film (starring David Hayter of MGS fame [fun-fact, fact-fans!])
- The [re-imagined Anime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guyver:_The_Bioboosted_Armor)

as well as a handful of other tie-ins and off shoots.

[image]

Many of the sequences, particularily in the original OVA featured a large amount of forest based battles.

Infact, when Shō Fukamachi first stumbles accross the Bio-boosted armour he is in a forest, and is immediately attacked by other Zoanoids in a prolonged sequence (that bridges 2 episodes in the re-imagined version).

Answer (score 1):

Based off of this... try Light Years. I don't know how old it really is. But people were captured and sent into a protal and came back robotic warriors, which the portal really was a gate to the future.

That's the best I got off of this.

Answer (score -1):

You might be referring to [Animorphs book series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs) which was also a [TV series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs_(TV_series)) and also became a Transformer like [toy line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs_(toy)).

Does [this video of the first episode](http://youtu.be/GnE354UcfpI) look familiar? Or [this character list](http://www.scholastic.com/animorphs/characters/)?

This is a cover from the book series contains a similar font / logo to the TV series (credit [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animorphs)):

[image]

Comment: I don't think the TV show had any robots in it (I don't think it lasted long enough to introduce the Chee)

Answer (score -3):

perhaps Princess Mononoke?  It was a Ghibli film, came out in '97, alot of it set in a forest and stuff...

Comment: There was nothing in Princess Mononoke that could even possibly pass as "like robots".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.